# Macro for Saving Solidworks parts as dxf files

Tags: macros, solidworks

I have to save a lot of dxf files from solidworks to use for a CNC machine.

I'm looking for help to create a macro to save the top view of a part as a .dxf in the same location as the solidworks file is saved.

I would like it to first save the solidworks part, and to replace any existing dxf if there's one with the same name already saved in that location.

I could find macros for drawing files and for sheet metal parts but have been unable to edit these to work for a normal part.

much appreciated if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

It will export the top view of the part to dxf

(Adapted from [ExportToDWG2](https://help.solidworks.com/2014/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IPartDoc~ExportToDWG2.html))

```
Option Explicit
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swPart As SldWorks.PartDoc
Dim sModelName As String
Dim sPathName As String
Dim varAlignment As Variant
Dim dataAlignment(11) As Double
Dim varViews As Variant
Dim dataViews(0) As String
Sub main()
Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swPart = swModel
sModelName = swModel.GetPathName
sPathName = Left(sModelName, Len(sModelName) - 6) & "dxf"
dataAlignment(0) = 0#
dataAlignment(1) = 0#
dataAlignment(2) = 0#
dataAlignment(3) = 1#
dataAlignment(4) = 0#
dataAlignment(5) = 0#
dataAlignment(6) = 0#
dataAlignment(7) = 0#
dataAlignment(8) = -1#
dataAlignment(9) = 0#
dataAlignment(10) = 1#
dataAlignment(11) = 0#
varAlignment = dataAlignment
dataViews(0) = "*Top"
varViews = dataViews
swPart.ExportToDWG2 sPathName, sModelName, swExportToDWG_e.swExportToDWG_ExportAnnotationViews, True, varAlignment, False, False, 0, varViews
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Thanks very much!! A MASSIVE timesaver for me.